# Java sort and merge

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a table TAB like

```
ID  RANK  NAME 
--- ----- -----
1   1     abc
1   2     def
1   4     xyz
2   1     pqr
2   5     def
2   3     stu
```

There are groups of data represented by the ID column. Groups can share a common name with different ranks. I merge and sort the above table using the query

```
  SELECT MAX(RANK) R, NAME
    FROM TAB
   WHERE ID in (1,2)
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY R
```

to get the result where the common names are merged to a single row, and sorted by rank (the max rank if two rows share the same name)

```
R     NAME 
----  ----- 
1     abc
1     pqr
3     stu
4     xyz
5     def
```

Now, instead of getting this combined result from the db, if I retrieve two resultsets based on each id in java, what is the most efficient way to merge and sort them in java?

Comment: Your question is not clear: what's the output of your query and how would you like to "merge & sort" it ? how the final output should look like ?

Comment: @alfasin sorry about that, I have updated the question with the expected result. By merge I mean rows which have same name need to be shown only one time, and if their ranks are different, max of their ranks will be shown on the merged row

Comment: the addition you made is good, but one part is still missing. Now you have the last input in two collections ? which collections includes which inputs ? and saying you'd like to merge it is still vague. You can use `HashMap<String, Integer>` mapping the unique names to ranks - is that what you're looking for ? if you need an ordered collection that won't be good - but I can't guess what your requirements are unless you specify thme ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the class `Entity` to store the rows of the result sets, you can use the following method `mergeAndSort` to merge and sort the entities in the same way, as in the above SQL statement.

```
final class Entity {
    private final int rank;
    private final String name;
    public Entity(int rank, String name) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getRank() { return rank; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
}

public static List<Entity> mergeAndSort(List<Entity> entities) {
    Map<String, Entity> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Entity current : entities) {
        Entity previous = map.get(current.getName());
        if (previous == null || previous.getRank() < current.getRank()) {
            map.put(current.getName(), current);
        }
    }
    List<Entity> result = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
    Collections.sort(result, new Comparator<Entity>() {
            public int compare(Entity lhs, Entity rhs) {
                return Integer.compare(lhs.getRank(), rhs.getRank());
            }
        });
    return result;
}
```